# ELB Instances are removed on failed healthchecks

Tags: amazon-elb, amazon-ecs

I'm running an ECS cluster with 4 ELB's. I have the annoying problem that my ELB's **remove** instances upon healtcheck failure. When my cluster rescale a task, it could be running on another instance so the instances need to be registered with the ELB, marked as OutOfService.

Is there a way to configure this behaviour?

Comment: Is this [AWS troubleshooting document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/ts-elb-healthcheck.html#ts-elb-healthcheck-autoscaling) helpful? If not, I would recommend adding a note to your question indicating that you have tried its suggestions.

Comment: I'm not using autoscaling, I've just 3 instances manually added to the ELB's.

Comment: *"my ELB's remove instances upon healtcheck failure"* Please be more specific, here.  What exactly does "remove" mean?  Remove from what?  From the ELB?  From ECS?  From existence?

Comment: Go to EC2 dashboard, select Load Balancers. Select loadbalance from list. Go to Instances tab. You see a list of instances with status field OutOfService or InService. From this list, they get magically removed.